# Convert a number of days in int?

Tags: ms-project

I'm trying to program a status bar in msproject and I'm stuck to find a way to convert my duration string into int
Ms Project returns a string like "8 days" or "8 hours",
Currently, the only way I found to do that it's to split my string in two I convert the first part in int and I look if the value I get is in h or D and after that I convert it but the problem is if I changed the language of my program, It doesn't work anymore so I'd like to know if it exists a function like 
Numberstyle.Currency for the duration

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue: How to display duration units fully spelled-out even if user has selected abbreviations, and in the native language.

The user can control how to display duration units. For example "d", "dy/dys", "day/days" for durations in days (in English). To get the fully spelled-out day label, in the user's language, change the [Project.DayLabelDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863992%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) setting to 2 and use the [GetField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/task-getfield-method-project) method to get the duration of a task as displayed.

Ideally, capture the values for all unit types when the add-in (or project) is loaded:

1. Create a new project
2. Set the [Project.DefaultDurationUnits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-defaultdurationunits-property-project?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to pjMinute
3. Set the [Project.MinuteLabelDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-minutelabeldisplay-property-project) to 2
4. Add a task, set a duration, use `GetField` to get the displayed duration in minutes.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for the remaining unit types: [Project.HourLabelDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-hourlabeldisplay-property-project?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [Project.DayLabelDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863992%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [Project.WeekLabelDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-weeklabeldisplay-property-project), [Project.MonthLabelDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-monthlabeldisplay-property-project),
6. Close and don't save the project

Alternatively, you can just display the duration as the user has selected.

Note: Durations can be displayed in years ([Project.YearLabelDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-yearlabeldisplay-property-project?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), but the default duration unit cannot be set to years.